# Programmatically Trigger Drag&Drop Events on Linux

Tags: x11, qt, drag-and-drop

I currently working on an interactive video stream application (implemented in PyQt5) which allows viewers of the stream to interact with the streamer's system, for example by moving the mouse cursor or opening programs.

I would also want to allow Drag&Drop through the stream from one device to the other. I was able to implement the drag part as well as transferring the data by using QWidget's dropEvent()-Function and a web server. However, I am struggling with triggering a drop event at certain coordinates on the streamer's system.
I had a look at xdnd as well as some applications such as [xcopy](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/utils/) already, but all of those seem to require the mouse for drag and drop.

**Is there any way to tell X11 to invoke a drop event with a certain payload at given coordinates without having to use the mouse?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are multiple ways to inject synthetic XEvents in C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319519/how-to-insert-synthetic-mouse-events-into-x11-input-queue

Answer (score 0):

Use [`xdotool`](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool).

```
xdotool mousedown 1 mousemove x y mouseup 1
```

Here first it clicks the left button and keep it pressed (`mousedown 1`). Then it drag it to coordinate x,y (`mousemove x y`). You can also use polar coordinate, with flag `--polar`, make coordiate relative to a window with `-w <window id>`. Also use relative coordination from current coordinate with `mousemove_relative` instead of `mousemove`. Finally it drops it, by releasing the click `mouseup 1`.

Here is a demo. I drag&dropped a file from one pan to another in Dolphin.
[image]

Note: I don't know if it'll suit your need, it is more cli-way than programatical. But you can make system call.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, this is not what I'm looking for. The Drag-Part happens on the other device. So I only need to simulate the drop (without performing the drag action before) of a certain file or content to a certain position.